# Desarrollo android: Se cierra la app al cambiar la actividad

Tags: java, android

Me encuentro desarrollando una app para un proyecto en mi Universidad, el tema es el siguiente: tengo 2 actividades, una de ellas es una Navigation drawer activity (NDA) y la otra es una activity en blanco (login) y estoy colocando un botón para saltar del login al home de la NDA, pero se cierra la app y no cambia de actividad.

esta es mi MainActivity

```
package com.example.myapplication;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button botonsaltar = findViewById(R.id.button);
        botonsaltar.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent saltar = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), home.class);
            startActivity(saltar);

        });
    }
```

y esta es mi NDA

```
public class home extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        com.example.myapplication.databinding.ActivityHomeBinding binding = ActivityHomeBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarHome.toolbar);
        binding.appBarHome.fab.setOnClickListener(view -> Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show());
        DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
        NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setOpenableLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_home);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_home);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

Comment: que información sobre el error te da el logcat? puedes revisarlo ejecutando adb logcat AndroidRuntime:e *:s -v tag en una consola con el dispositivo de prueba conectado (ya sea físico o emulador) y ejecutando la app nuevamente

Comment: Deberías controlar el LogCat en el momento en que tu app se cierra